# Defining a "good" periodic function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose I have a function $f$. Suppose there is some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(a)=f(b)$. What are the conditions on $f$ so I know that I can "loop" $f$ to get a smooth periodic function? I guess I would have to look at the higher order taylor coefficents on one side, right? Like, if I looked at $\frac{df}{dt}$ as $t$ approached $b$ and $\frac{df}{dt}$ as $t$ approached $a$ and you did this for all $\frac{d^nf}{dt^n}$ then you would get a good function of this nature. Is this a good way to think about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes we should check, assuming $f$ and $g$ of class $C^n$ and $a<b$, that

$$\lim_{x\to a^+} f^{(n)}(x)=\lim_{x\to b^-} f^{(n)}(x)$$

holds s.t. we have a periodic function of class $C^n$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want $(a,b+\epsilon)\to\Bbb R$, $x\mapsto \begin{cases}f(x)&x\le b\\f(x-b+a)&x\ge b\end{cases}$ to be smooth at $b$ (and of course also in $(a,b)$